# Get emitted events in hyperledger composer

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have emitted a event after added asset.

```
    //adding data in asset done
    .
    .
    Var eventdata = getFactory().newEvent('org.samplepath','MyEvent'');
    eventdata.id = 1;
    eventdata.name = 'firstevent';
    emit(eventdata);
```

Now I want to `get/retrieve` the emitted event in `nodejs` api.
Can anyone tell me how to do that in node js api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Using a webSocket You can retrieve event data.

```
// Listen for events
Events.URL_TRADE = 'ws://localhost:3000';

this.socket = new WebSocket(Events.URL_TRADE);
this.socket.addEventListener('open', evt => this.doSocketOpen(evt));
this.socket.addEventListener('close', evt => this.doSocketClose(evt));
this.socket.addEventListener('message', evt => this.doSocketMessage(evt));
```

I recommend the following links.

1. [Event example](https://github.com/IBM/BlockchainEvents-CompositeJourney)
2. [Hyperledger Event](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/publishing-events).

Hope it will help you :)